What is a condensate, and is water a condensate?
So I just noticed, one says that water condenses.
But I would define a condensate as when symmetry such as translation or rotation is broken, which is clearly not the case for gas into water. (I think in fact that these two are strictly speaking not different phases, as there exists a path in parameter space that connects them without non-analycity of the partition function.)
So what is the precise definition of condensate?
EDIT: So to address some points: Yes, there exists paths that connect liquid water to gaseous water that exhibits a sudden change in (derivatives) of the thermodynamical potential. That isn't the point however. The symmetries of both systems are still the same.

"Condensate" is a noun, not a verb.

"one says that water condensates." Not sure if you actually saw that written somewhere, or if it is a grammar error. "Condense" is a verb and we conjugate it as: "It condenses." For example, "water vapor condenses into water, which can be called a condensate."

Words get overloaded and have more than one meaning.   Condensate does not have one exclusive definition.

Liquid water is much denser than the vapor. The change from vapor to liquid is a standard English usage for ‘to condense’ or ‘condensation’. See, for example, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condense

@BowlOfRed So what about physics? What do physicists mean by condensate? Not the colloquial usage of condensate.

I believe it is called a condensate because if you look at the momentum space distribution function $\langle n_k\rangle$, it looks like there is a sharp transition where all the particles "condense" at $k=0$, not unlike water vapor condensing into a dense drop.
